# Fixing CVSNT 2.5.05

Tags: tortoisecvs, cvsnt

TortoiseCVS comes with bundled CVSNT binaries.
The older version(s) came with CVSNT 2.5.03, which turned out to have a security vulnerability.
The latest version (1.12.5) comes with CVSNT 2.5.05 that has several issues:

- It nags with pop-ups that urge you to buy the commercial version.
- It inserts advertisements into commit notes.
- It has a bug that leaves Windows command-line consoles in a messed-up state.
- The sources (GPL) are not easily obtainable.

Some references:
- [What is going on with CVSNT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327285/what-is-going-on-with-cvsnt)
- [Batch scripts no longer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913296/batch-scripts-no-longer-work)

Recently, somebody posted this to the TortoiseCVS mailing list:

> i found the sources and made the following fixes
>   version_fu.h - set the "suite" flag to avoid popups and advertisement
>   win32.cpp - saved the original codepage and restored it on exit
>
> take it from http://www.mediafire.com/?ys93oh4bdj1auby
>
> only the cvsnt.dll needs to be compiled

I downloaded the sources and tried compiling them.  Unfortunately they seem to need quite a number of other packages (openssl, iconv, mysql, postgres, etc...  I lost count) that are open source but still need to be hunted for...
Combined with my limited time and the lack of tools (I don't have VS2008) I gave up on the effort to build it myself.

I tried contacting the author of the message, but he is in a similar position (and does not use CVSNT anymore).

Contacting the TortoiseVCS maintainer also proved fruitless:

> That is not a project I am going to undertake.
>   TortoiseCVS is very low on my list of priorities these days.

If anybody is willing to build the "fixed" CVSNT.DLL from the provided sources, and make it available, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score -3):

Sure - you can get it here - compiled in a single installer which includes TortoiseCVS and the latest CVSNT code with lots of bug fixes:
http://march-hare.com/cvsnt/features/tortoise/

The small fee we charge is to cover our costs of developing and distributing the software including the license fees for MSDN and financial contributions to related projects such as the TortoiseCVS project, Bugzilla project, FSF etc. etc.  The source code is included in the price.

Remember that Free Software is about Freedom (like the Free Press) not about price:
http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html

Comment: [£425.00 Excl. VAT](http://store.march-hare.com/s.nl/sc.2/category.215/.f) is a small fee for just the client community edition??? The competition, which also works on Windows and is easier to set up, [SmartCVS, starts at $79](http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/purchase). Both seem to have stopped further development around 2011 though. But well, CVS is retiring itself...

Comment: [£85 Excl. VAT](http://march-hare.com/cvspro/) if you want to latest up to date version (as of writing - last updated 24 March 2017).  We charge more for ancient code from 2007 to discourage people from using bug and security hole ridden software.